# 5V to 3V3 - Sensor for Arduino 3V3

Tags: arduino, sensor

I am trying to make a circuit using a 3V3 Arduino and other modules working on 3V3, but I have a problem with [an analog water sensor](https://www.thingbits.net/products/dfrobot-gravity-analog-water-pressure-sensor) I need to use. The output is a voltage range is from 0.5V to 4.5V.

I think I cannot use 4.5V signal on an analog pin of an Arduino working at 3V3.

So I have a basic idea like solution. 
- Use a 5V step-up voltage regulator from 3V7 li-on battery for the water sensor
- Then using a voltage resistor divider to convert from 5V (sensor output) to 3V3. 
- Then connect to the Arduino and inside make line code with a simple equation where I can recover the 5Volt value.

For example
[image]

Will I will lose resolution doing this? Is it a bad idea?

EXTRA QUESTION

To ensure that I will not lose resolution, what do I need to check? Maybe the minimum step voltage in the ouput of sensor? For example 5mv minimum of variation, then 5mv*voltage_divider = 3.3mv ... Then 10 bit of resolution of ADC in Arduino is enough? I got a 3.22mv resolution (3.3/1023)

Comment: Your convert back equation will need to be of the form Y = mX + b to account for the 0.5 V offset at zero scale.

Comment: You are right! I will only need to take care of resolution of ADC for output of voltage divide, if not i will not recover some variations ?

Comment: How much of the range of the pressure sensor are you using?

Comment: It is a basic sensor I think for prototype circut...
Pressure Measurement Range: 0~1.6 Mpa
Output Voltage: 0.5~4.5 V

Comment: @asterix I see that in the data, but what range do you require? Are you really going to use the sensor right out to it's limit? This makes a big difference to the gain you need.

Comment: Oh I see... I don't know the range effective, I only I design the essential circuit for a prototype. Sorry for that :(

Answer (score 2):

That's the standard way to do it but you might consider lowering your resistors so that the net effective impedance seen by the Arduino's ADC input is only a few kohm. Maybe use 5k1 and 10 kohm. You'll find in the data sheet that the ATMEGA328 chip likes to have a source impedance not greater than 10 kohm.

You might also consider adding a capacitor across the (now) 10 kohm resistor to offer some anti alias filtering. If you can manage 100 nF that would be a good default choice but it depends on the bandwidth of the signals you wish to convert.

Comment: Using a simple divider does NOT get rid of the sensor offset, so reduces the signal resolution.

Answer (score 1):

With 4.7K and 10K the values (3v3 Arduino 1023 max) are:

````
+5V Source
^
|    4.7K    AX      10K
----/\/\/\----*----/\/\/\------GND

5V Source    AX        Analog AX
--------   ------    ------------
  4.8       3.31        1023
  4.5       3.12        964
  4.0       2.80        865
  3.5       2.45        757
  3.3       2.30        711
  3.0       2.13        658
  2.5       1.76        544

```
````

Answer (score 0):

> Scaling a 5V sensor with offset into a 3.3V full scale A/D

Since the sensor has a large offset (approximately 0.5V) and a span of 4V you have to scale the input and provide an adjustable offset control.

One possible solution is to use a single rail to rail op-amp powered by the 3.3V supply. This provides self limiting since the VCC rail and ground become the input limit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMrL1U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [TLV9001](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv9001.pdf) or [TLV6001](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv6001.pdf) are good low cost opamp candidates. 
R1 and R2 give a scale factor of 0.825.
R4 and R5 provide offset control.
Full scale resolution is 4V/1024 = 3.9mV (input voltage resolution)

Update: added element to allow the simulator to run. The output looks just fine.    The small amount of clipping on the output is due to the incorrect value of the offset Rin (R4 and R5)
[image]

Note that this is of course an inverting configuration, so at zero (0.5v) sensor output the input to the A/D is 3.3V. I assume you can cope with this inversion.

Think of the circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMAZFf.png)</sup>

To understand the circuit read [this](http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf). Particularly read section 3.3 and 3.4.
If you don't understand opamps as attenuators (this one is stable at less than unity gain) you might read [this](https://www.edn.com/design/analog/4461648/Unique-compensation-technique-tames-high-bandwidth-voltage-feedback-op-amps-) excellent article.

Comment: I dont know how works your circut :|

Comment: It's a simple inverting op-amp. Perhaps you could start here: http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf  Read the section 3.3 on inverting op-amps.

Comment: Vout = R2(0.5-2.5)/R1 + R2(3.3-2.5)/(R5+R4) = 1,649484536 + 0,711111111 = 2,36 Volts. Where R5+R4 is 9K. I cant get a value 3.3 volt :(

Comment: Calculate your signal levels around the 2.5V reference NOT absolute Vin.

Comment: WOW the output is perfectly... I will not sleep if I cannot do the same using equations.
You are great!! Thanks very much

Comment: You can do the equations, just remember that the sensor is actually +/-2V on a 2.5V center point. The Offset Vin is 3.3-2.5=0.8V. Remember to upvote the answer if it is correct for you.

Comment: I cant vote : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. SORRY

Question. Why the signal have a fase of 90 degree. I mean when input is 0.5v the output is 3.3v and 4.5v vin 0V ?

Comment: @asterix The phase difference is 180deg because it is an inverting opamp. As the signal increase the output decreases. The gain for the signal path is -0.825.

Comment: okay you are right!! So applying a negative symbol to line code all will be okay. Thanks
Wait but the your answer Full scale resolution is 4V/1024 = 3.9mV (input voltage resolution)

why not 3.3v/1024 = 3.2mv . The input is the output of your adapter circuit

Comment: The resolution is of the INPUT signal, not the scaled signal. Your full scale signal range is from 0.5-4.5V=4V. So 4V/1024 is the resolution --> 3.9mV. If full scale at the input was 3.2mV, then the maximum voltage represented would be only 3.2V ….but you know it's 4V full scale range.